# How can I pass value to FacebookRedirectLoginHelper in PHP

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I use Facebook PHP SDK and trying to send token-id from one page to another. I use this code - http://www.krizna.com/demo/login-with-facebook-using-php/. I use

`$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://www.krizna.com/fbconfig.php' );`

I have tried sending value like this :

```
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://www.krizna.com/fbconfig.php?value='.$value );
```

but I do not get value in `fbconfig.php` file when I try:

```
$value = $_GET['value'];
```

I have also used session for sending values but it does not work. How can I send value to FacebookRedirectLoginHelper (`fbconfig.php`)?

**fbconfig.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

$value = $_GET['value_new'];

$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => $config->facebook->app_id,
    'app_secret' => $config->facebook->app_secret
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
try {
    if ($access_token = $helper->getAccessToken()) {

        try {
            // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object with the requested fields
            $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=name,id,email,picture', $access_token);
            $user = $response->getGraphUser();
            $fbid = $user->getId();            // To Get Facebook ID
            $fbfullname = $user->getName();    // To Get Facebook full name
            $femail = $graphObject->getEmail();// To Get Facebook email ID
            $_SESSION['FBID'] = $fbid;
            $_SESSION['FULLNAME'] = $fbfullname;
            $_SESSION['EMAIL'] = $femail;
            //Then do whatever you want with that data

            $value = $_SESSION['value'];

            header("Location: index.php?value_new=$value");

            } catch (\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
            error_log('Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage());
        } catch (\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
            error_log('Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
} catch (\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    error_log('Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage());
} catch (\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    error_log('Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['FBID'])): ?><!--  After user login  -->
<div class="container">
    <h1>value <?php $value_new = $_GET['value_new']; echo $value_new; ?></h1>
</div>
<? endif ?>
```

Comment: The url you give FacebookRedirectLoginHelper is the url that facebook redirects back to, they will strip out any query string I'm sure. Why does fbconfig need the token? And I'm sure this is possible with $_SESSION

Comment: I tried with  $_SESSION but it's always null. How can I use it ?

Comment: Hi Jason. I'm just taking a look at some of my code for this, I'll hopefully get you an answer written.

Comment: I would also change your app_id and secret as you've now posted them publicly here!

Comment: yup Thanks. Please let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be trying to pass the facebook Access Token via the query string / `$_GET[]` superglobal. What you should be using is what facebook recommends, which is the `$_SESSION[]` superglobal.

Since you are trying to pass the access token from one page to another, lets call the access token on the first page `$access_token`. To pass it to another page do the following:

**page 1:**

```
<?php 
  session_start(); //the very top of your document
  // ... other code ...
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $access_token;
  // ... other code ...
?>
```

**page 2:**

```
<?php 
  session_start(); //the very top of your document
  // ... other code ...
  $access_token = $_SESSION['access_token'];
  // ... other code ...
?>
```

That should work, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Replaced session with cookies.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is using the Facebook PHP SDK v5.1.2, and is adapted from the method I have working in my own projects. It also assumes composer autoloading is being used.

Login Page

```
session_start();
$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => $config->facebook->app_id, //Change these to yours
    'app_secret' => $config->facebook->app_secret
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['email'];
$this->view->facebook_url = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://www.krizna.com/fbconfig.php', $permissions);
```

`fbconfig.php` (or whatever you want your redirect page to be)

```
session_start();
$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => $config->facebook->app_id,
    'app_secret' => $config->facebook->app_secret
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
try {
     if ($access_token = $helper->getAccessToken()) {

        try {
            // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object with the requested fields
            $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=name,id,email,picture', $access_token);
            $user = $response->getGraphUser();
            $fbid = $user->getId();              // To Get Facebook ID
            $fbfullname = $user->getName(); // To Get Facebook full name
            $femail = $graphObject->getEmail();    // To Get Facebook email ID
            $_SESSION['FBID'] = $fbid;           
            $_SESSION['FULLNAME'] = $fbfullname;
            $_SESSION['EMAIL'] =  $femail;
            //Then do whatever you want with that data
        } catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
            error_log('Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage());
        } catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
            error_log('Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

} catch (\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    error_log('Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage());
} catch (\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    error_log('Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Hopefully that gives you a hand up. I don't doubt that my code has been adapted from previous StackOverflow answers or tutorials.

Comment: I have tried sending value from fbconfig.php to index.php by session and get value but it's null in both the cases. How can I set/pass the value to index.php ?

Comment: What and why are we trying to send that value? The latest Facebook should deal with tokens for us?

Comment: It's the token which I have generated. That has nothing to do with facebook . How can I pass that value to index.php?

Comment: When you generate it. `$_SESSION['token'] = $token_value`. And then when you want to get it. `$token_value = $_SESSION['token']`.

Comment: When are you setting it? And when are you trying to read it? Is the facebook auth working?

Comment: fb auth is working  but session value is null when I get back to index.php from fbconfig.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111564/discussion-between-nathan-edwards-and-jason).